# Making certain buffers invisible to commands involving "all" or bufdo

Tags: terminal, buffers, plugin-nerdtree

For my projects I generally open several tabs some of which might involve terminals or directory trees or quickfix (since ShellCheck sends its error messages there for instance).

When I want to use commands such as `:wa` or `:bufdo %s/pattern/to/ce` I either get annoying warning messages (ok, but not great) or the command fails because these buffers are unmodifiable (not ok).

Is there a way to make such buffers invisible to commands that target all buffers? I am imagining a flag I can set when creating these buffers or something I can do after creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider loading relevant buffers into the args, quickfix, or location list and using the related commands (`:argdo`, `:cdo`, etc.).

You could also set a buffer variable and do something like

```
:bufdo if get(b:, 'mydontskipvar', v:false) | … | endif
```

Comment: It's also _possible_ that `nobuflisted` and `buftype` options might help

Comment: I decided to go along with tmux when ever I needed a split. I find it more clean. However I will accept this as the answer as there seems to be really no other way

Comment: @Sina are you saying you split tmux with vim to open a new file? I do sometimes have multiple vims in multiple tmux panes, but one-per-file would be a bit excessive to me

Comment: No not one per file, I use tmux when I want to have split workspaces where one work space is associated to say the header files and the other split is associated to source files. So I only have the relevant files in each work space and name completion etc works much more flawlessly and global buffer operations are faster. Of course once in a while I might need to open other files which do not exist in the workspace but still much better than having 30 files open in every window.